# Remove cache on DomainService/DomainContext on the server from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, dynamics-crm, wcf-ria-services

I'm migrating a part of an app from Silverlight to ASP.NET, the Silverlight part uses RIA Services agains a Dynamics CRM. I'm reusing the DomainService from ASP.NET but have cache problems, so modifying an entity in a child window results in no new data from the parent if refreshed in less than a certain period of time, but the fresh data is already in the database.

I know you can override the cache behavior from a Silverlight client as stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953553/disable-caching-of-domaincontext-domaindatasource-in-silverlight-ria-services). But is this possible in an ASP.NET application?

I've also tried decorating the GetContacts method in the DomainService with `[OutputCache(OutputCacheLocation.None, 0)]` but it doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the CrmDataContext class, which the DomainService uses. There's no documented way to clear it's cache, but there's a way on [removing contents from the cache](http://danielrozo.es/web/asp-net/avoid-cache-crmdatacontext).